# Cannot use object of type MongoId as array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Im having a problem printing out the values inside a 2d array using echo, it works prefectly using print_r:

```
print_r($array);
```

The result of which is :

```
Array ( [0] => MongoId Object 
( [$id] => 57a789b7ce2350b40e000029 ) [1] => MongoId Object 
( [$id] => 57a72d35ce2350681200002b ) [2] => 3 )
```

However when i try to access the values using:

```
echo $similar[0][1];
//or
echo $similar[0][0];
```

I get the error : 'Cannot use object of type MongoId as array'

I have also tried different types of loops from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822238/echo-a-multi-dimensional-array) incase the error was triggered by accessing the values specifically by element number, however i got the same error and im unsure why. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Even this doesn't work? echo $array[0]['_id']; echo $array[1]['_id'];

Comment: Ok no actually made a mistake yes i still get the error for one 'echo $similar[0]['_id'];' , for the second one $similar['_id'][1]; nothing is printed but no error either....which is better but still unsure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$similar[0]` is an MongoId object, and want to access its `$id` then you must use `$similar[0]->{'$id'})`

in your example elements 0 and 1 are MongoId objects, while element 2 is an integer of 3.

So this is how you print them all

```
echo $similar[0]->{'$id'}) # gives 57a789b7ce2350b40e000029
echo $similar[1]->{'$id'}) # gives 57a72d35ce2350681200002b
echo $similar[2] # gives 3
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the tip!